# MIPS Stack- Erasing Contents Clarification

Tags: stack, mips

My Textbook says: Notice in this example, you aren't actually erasing the stack contents. If you're storing secret data, you should overwrite it with zeroes, or (ideally) garbage data. For
now, we can just leave our garbage lying around.

[image]

Aren't the contents that are saved on the stack removed after executing this?

```
add $30, $30, $4
```

Since it pops off all the saved contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merely incrementing the stack pointer does not change the contents of memory below the stack.  It's the same as working with a string variable in C:

```
char str[200] = { "    Secret data" };

strcpy(str, "foo");
```

At this point the variable's useful value by C convention is "foo".  But of course the array contains

```
foo\0Secret data\0< 184 more zero bytes >
```

Just as a function that cares to look can see the secret data in the string, another function or process running malicious code that knows your code doesn't erase its stack could read old "popped" data there. If it's a password or other value conferring privilege, the bad guys are ahead.